# Gimp starts but then doesn't open (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS )

Tags: 14.04, gimp

after having upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Gimp did keep working properly for some time.

If I now open it (via either dash or terminal) it seems to start alright, the loading bar and everything is displayed, but once the Gimp symbol is displayed left-hand in the starter nothing else happens. No document, nothing. Just the symbol.

So far none of the suggestions I've found here has worked.
Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you run `gimp` in a terminal and then paste the output here?

Comment: You may need to wipe GIMP's cache files. I know that when updates are done, GIMP usually spazzes at startup until you wipe the data it's stored wherever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

I think finally uninstalling and installing again did the deal. Gimp is working properly again. Thank you.